# SharePoint Unable to Store Value to Library List

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I have a web control and I am trying to insert the value into my SP List. 
But the value did not get inserted. I am now trying out with a fixed string value but it does not work too. The column value of the record is empty.

**Code snippet:**

```
<%-- Selected Header --%>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionC">Selected Header(s)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listFolder" CssClass="fileHeight" Style="width: 100%;" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="onListFolderClick();"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var list = SPHelper.GetListByUrl(ErmsConfig.GetString(ErmsConfig.Config.BackendGeneration));
var item = list.Items.Add();

item["RequestedBy"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

//Item below does not get inserted
item["SelectedHeaders"] = ("TEST 1234");

item.Update();
```

**List Structure:**
[image]

**List Records:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Also, Have you tried surrounding it with try-catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why are using brackets (paranthesis) around the text value '("TEST 1234")'.
remove them and try again.